# XSD - Need two separate choice options

Tags: xml, xsd

I am writing some XSD and I only have a basic understanding of the `<choice>` tag. I have it working with one section, but not another section that has an `attribute`.

For example, all elements are optional, but if I don't have one, then I need to have the other. This is fine if there is 2 elements, but I have 3.

Look at the schema section below. I can either have `message` or `scan` and not `include`, or I can have `include` and not `message` or `scan`.

```
       <xs:element name="messages">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="n:properties"/>

        <xs:choice>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="n:message" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="n:scan" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>

          <xs:element ref="n:scan"/>
        </xs:choice>

              <xs:attribute name="include"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>
```

At the moment, this is working for `message` and `scan` but gives me an error on `include` obviously, because I don't have the choice put in there yet.

Can anyone show me some samples of how I'd do `(message OR scan) OR include`?

Thanks

Comment: What keeps you from making the `include` attribute an element?

Comment: Well the point of it is to include another file that defines any number of `message` elements, eg `<messages include="messages/moreMessages.xml"/>`. This way its a self closing tag and is just more human readable, especially when including a number of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the simplest way to say "either A or B or C" is to make A, B, and C all be elements and write

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element ref="A"/>
  <xs:element ref="B"/>
  <xs:element ref="C"/>
</xs:choice>
```

An alternative would be to say "including messages from another file is not the same as specifying a message" and define both `n:messages` (which contains either a `message` or a `scan`) and `n:message-inclusion` (which points to another file).  In the parent element allow either.  Or define an abstract `message-thingy` element and put `n:messages` and `n:message-inclusion` into its substitution group.

A second alternative:  move to XSD 1.1 and use an assertion to enforce the rule that the `include` attribute is present iff the children are absent.